# What documents are required to extend a German Aufenthaltserlaubnis as a research assistant working towards a PhD?

Tags: germany, indian-citizens

The applicant is an Indian national in the state of Rhineland-Palatinate and has already booked an appointment with the local authority.

The applicant's contract as a research assistant (wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter) has been extended by one year to continue working towards a PhD. We would like to know what documents are required for this application, with sources if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As their site states, this is something that you should ask them beforehand, since it is dependent in the individual situation.

> The applicant's contract as a research assistant (wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter) has been extended by one year to continue working towards a PhD.

Since the contract has changed since the last application, taking the new contract with you would be advised.

---

> [BUS Rheinland-Pfalz - Elektronischer Aufenthaltstitel (eAT) Verlängerung](https://bus.rlp.de/detail?pstId=201692317#panel2)
> **Welche Unterlagen werden benötigt?**
> Reisepass und weitere Unterlagen - je nachdem, welche Verfahren vorausgegangen sind. **Da der Einzelfall entscheidend ist, sollten die erforderlichen Unterlagen vorher bei der zuständigen Stelleangefragt werden.**
>
> > **Which documents are required?**
> > Passport and other documents - depending on the previous procedure. **Since the individual case is decisive, the necessary documents should be requested from the responsible office beforehand.**